# How to log all axios calls from one place in code

Tags: axios

I am using axios for a react application and I would like to log all axios calls that I'm making anywhere in the app. I'm already using a single global instance of axios via the create function and I am able to log a generic console.log. However I would like more info like function being called, parameters, etc.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

The best way to do this would be an interceptor. Each interceptor is called before a request/response. In this case a logging interceptor would be.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2))
  return request
})

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
  return response
})
```

or something to that effect.

It's good that you're using a new instance of axios:

```
const api = axios.create({
  timeout: 1000
})
```

That way you can call

```
api.interceptors[...]
```

Comment: It will be worthy to note that without the `return response`, the code will break at the interceptor

Comment: In `api.interceptors[...]`, the `[...]` part is the previously demonstrated code. They just didn't want to type `api.interceptors.request.use...` and `api.interceptors.response.use...` in the answer again.

Comment: I get `Type Error: Cannot read property request of undefined` in first `request` keywords of `api.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log('Starting Request', request)
  return request
})`. How to fix this error?

Comment: How can I make these interceptors work only during development and not in release mode?

Comment: @Satyam I would suggest using a logger different from console.log that allows you to configure which log levels are enabled. e.g. winston. Your framework may have alternative configurable facades.

Comment: Didn't know about it. You helped me a lot. Finally i fixed my code using this debugging method! Thanks!!!

Comment: This gives me "circular dependency" error. Wrapping it like this fixed it: let { inspect } = require('util'); JSON.stringify(inspect(response), null, 2). Where util is a standard node package

Comment: The line:  console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2)) does not log the request that is sent to the server. I have seen that axios adds additional headers based on the payload after that. That can be seen in the error (error.request._currentRequest._header) if an error happens. I find that very confusing. I wonder how nobody has this question. The interceptor does not seem to show the real headers that were sent

Comment: The response interceptor needs to be work with `reseponse.data` to avoid circular json issue, 
```axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
      logger.debug('Axios Response: %s', JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
      return response;
    });```

Comment: this doesn't seem to log errors

Answer (score 30):

### Use [`axios-debug-log`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-debug-log)

1. `npm install --save axios-debug-log`
2. `require('axios-debug-log')` before any axios call
3. Set the environment variable `DEBUG=axios`

By default, you'll see logs like the following:

```
  axios POST /api/auth/login +0ms
  axios 200  (POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login) +125ms
  axios POST /api/foo +0ms
  axios 200  (POST http://localhost:8080/api/foo) +15ms
```

Refer to [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-debug-log) for configuration and customization options.

Comment: Hi i wanted to ask where can i see this ? is it in file?



  axios POST /api/auth/login +0ms
  axios 200  (POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login) +125ms
  axios POST /api/foo +0ms
  axios 200  (POST http://localhost:8080/api/foo) +15ms

Comment: where to set DEBUG =axios. could you please provide the steps (I am a beginnner)

Comment: @PoojaRajendranC set that before you start the code up `DEBUG=axios server.js` in the terminal

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can intercept all requests using an "interceptor", and log inside of it:  https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors

Answer (score 3):

**Use [axios-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-logger)**

When you send a request in nodejs, you need to show the log to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wrap the `axios.request` function in a Promise.

```
function loggedRequest(config) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.request(config)
    .then((res) => {
      // log success, config, res here
      resolve(res);      
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // same, log whatever you want here
      reject(err);
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score -12):

Here's an NPM package for MySQL that let's you log all axios requests https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-logger-mysql , I hope this helps.