# Middleware for logging in React similar to Multer for Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, npm

I am working on a React app which makes a lot of API calls, is there a middleware which can basically intercept all calls and console them similar to Multer for Express server.

In addition, I wonder if there is a general logger for events like errors, APIs, etc. in React.

Comment: The netwrok tab can show only xhr,

Answer (score 1):

Although, you can see the request & response data in the `Chrome Network Tab`, but if you still want to see it logged in the console for some reason, Yes! there is a way.

If you are using `axios` to make API calls, you can use `interceptors`. Refer to [this part of axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors). You can do a `console.log` in the interceptor. Or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754655/7835882).

If you are using `fetch` to make API calls, you can still define a custom function. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42952086/7835882).

I think this will solve your problem. Good Luck!